# dateTimeFormatter short time-zone name not returned

Tags: java, java-8, date

The short timezone name is not returning for the below code in java8, it returns "-08:00" instead

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-01-22T08:07:59.179-08:00");
ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
System.out.println(dateTime1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z")));
```

this outputs: 2020-01-22 08:07:59.179 -08:00

Please let know which format input will produce "2020-01-22 08:07:59.179 PST"

Comment: FYI: an offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, positive if ahead of UTC, negative if behind UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. Politicians inexplicably choose the change the offset of their jurisdictions surprisingly often. Another thing: 2-4 letter codes such as `PST`  are not actually time zones; they are not standardized and are not even unique. Real time zone names are in `Continent/Region` format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to add the zoneId to your date:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    ZonedDateTime dateTime1 =
       ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-01-22T08:07:59.179-08:00")
      .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));

    ZonedDateTime dateTime2 = // I'm at CET
       ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-01-22T08:07:59.179+01:00")
      .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

    System.out.println(dateTime1.format(DateTimeFormatter
                                       .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z")));
    System.out.println(dateTime2.format(DateTimeFormatter
                                       .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z")));

/* prints
2020-01-22 08:07:59.179 GMT-08:00
2020-01-22 08:07:59.179 CET
*/
  }
}
```